# table with ng-repeat not displaying correctly

Tags: angularjs

Folks I am using a simple ng-repeat directive to display data in table. 
However when the directive renders, the first column takes up all the space and dis-figures the table.

Take a look at the plnkr here : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hahh4uyQ130zOS8noC3D

please focus on the file layout.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in header" class="header-cells" style="width:{{element.width}}px">
      <th drop-down-sort-menu>{{element.column}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in body">
      <td ng-repeat="h in header" row="{{$parent.$index}}" col="{{$index}}" style="width:{{element.width}}px">{{element[h.column]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am sure it's something minor. any clues

Comment: You had a few problems.  http://plnkr.co/edit/coVXMyzSGKF0EdrkObsL?p=preview  I can't post an answer because someone flagged your post.

Comment: @James, it would be a good idea to make your questions a little more clear to avoid them being flagged.

Comment: Craig.. your solution worked..thanks a lot .. i can't mark your answer as correct unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I believe you problem is that for the headers, you have 4 TRs with only one TH, as opposed to one TR with 4 THs. For this reason, the cells on your headers are not matching the cells on your body.

Do the first ng-repeat at the TH level.

Give it a try and let me know.